# how to detach an inner screen session

Tags: gnu-screen

I usually use gnu screen like this: 
   1. start a screen session for all my tasks
   2. When I login to a machine, I connect to a screen session (screen -x) made by my colleague (so this makes it an "inner screen")

Problem is, when I need to detach from the "inner screen" via ":detach" command or ctrl+a+d, I get detached from my main screen (in #1).

Is it possible to detach from "inner screen"?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to the inner screen. That is, to detach the inner screen press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>. Alternatively press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, and write `:detach`.

I also work with the same screen setup as you and found it more convenient to change the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> shortcut to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (lower case "L") on my local machine. That way you can access the inner screen directly with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> instead of the tedious <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>. To do that add this to your local `~/.screenrc`:

```
escape ^La
```